# Mdi.Children in one function

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to open other forms in my main Form. It is working but I have to create a function for every option in the menu. Can i create a function that when I click on a certain menu item it uses one function and in that function it searches which Form I want to open.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
class functionsHoofdvenster
{
  // Scherm in scherm functie voor frmTeams
  public void frmTeamsAanroep(frmHoofdvenster frmhoofdvenster)
  {
  // Scherm in scherm weergeven (bool wordt naar true veranderd als mdi.child aan staat)
    bool gevonden = false;
    // Form met naam frmTeams zoeken en selecteren
    foreach (Form x in frmhoofdvenster.MdiChildren)
    {
      if (x.Text == "frmTeams")
      {
        x.Activate();
        gevonden = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (gevonden == false)
    {
      frmTeams f = new frmTeams();
      f.MdiParent = frmhoofdvenster;
      f.Show();
    }
  }

  // Scherm in scherm functie voor frmSpelers
  public void frmSpelersAanroep(frmHoofdvenster frmhoofdvenster)
  {
  // Scherm in scherm weergeven (bool wordt naar true veranderd als mdi.child aan staat)
    bool gevonden = false;
    // Form met naam frmTeams zoeken en selecteren
    foreach (Form x in frmhoofdvenster.MdiChildren)
    {
      if (x.Text == "frmSpelers")
      {
        x.Activate();
        gevonden = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (gevonden == false)
    {
      frmSpelers s = new frmSpelers();
      s.MdiParent = frmhoofdvenster;
      s.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

And the main form where I call the function

```
// Logical Layer aanroepen als ll
Logical_Layer.functionsHoofdvenster ll = new Logical_Layer.functionsHoofdvenster();

private void teamsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ll.frmTeamsAanroep(this);
}

private void spelersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ll.frmSpelersAanroep(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using generics and reflection to show or create your forms:

```
private void ShowForm<T>() {
  bool formFound = false;
  foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren) {
    if (f.GetType() == typeof(T)) {
      f.Activate();
      formFound = true;
    }
  }
  if (!formFound) {
    var f = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    ((Form)f).MdiParent = this;
    ((Form)f).Show();       
  }
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
ShowForm<frmTeams>();
ShowForm<frmSpelers>();
```

You would have to replace "this" with your MDI instance of frmHoofdvenster.  My example assumes your child forms do not have custom constructors.